# Error duplicate entry when record begins with an underscore

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I have a Perl script which calls a store procedure in MySQL.  The stored procedure is very simple, it checks to see if a record exists, and updates it if it does.  If the record does not exist it will create it.  The basic code looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`me`@`%` PROCEDURE `updateClientUsage`(IN inDate DATE, IN inPort SMALLINT(4), IN inOwner VARCHAR(255), IN inName VARCHAR(255), IN inEmailed TINYINT(1))
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM client_usage WHERE port = inPort AND name = inName) THEN
        UPDATE client_usage SET date = inDate, emailed = '0' WHERE port = inPort AND name = inName;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO client_usage (date, port, owner, name, emailed) 
        VALUES (inDate, inPort, inOwner, inName, inEmailed);
    END IF;
END
```

When I run my script it works fine until this procedure tries to update a record that starts with an underscore (the name field starts with an underscore).  I get an error that there is a duplicate entry.
Does anyone know why that is the case?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? Also, are you sure it's trying to UPDATE and not INSERT if you're getting a duplicate error? Are there any constraints on the table? If so, what are they?

Comment: I think it is trying to insert when it should be updating.  The error message is: DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '_ClientThatStartsWithUnderscore'

Comment: This is probably another problem, however you assign a string `'0'` to `emailed`, but the parameter `inEmailed` is declared as `TINYINT(1)`.

Comment: Hmm, I changed the data type for emailed and a few other fields to match what they are in table and that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if there is a unique index or a primary key on `port` and `name`. If the primary key or a unique index are defined on other columns, you may get duplicate keys even after your check `WHERE port = inPort AND name = inName`.

Comment: Part and Name are my 2 primary keys.  I was able to fix it by changing the datatypes for inDate, inName, etc... to match the datatypes in the table.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the condition, since it can be specified in the where-clause (the test is the same)

```
   UPDATE client_usage 
      SET date = inDate, emailed = '0'
    WHERE port = inPort AND name = inName
       ;

   INSERT INTO client_usage (date, port, owner, name, emailed) 
   VALUES (inDate, inPort, inOwner, inName, inEmailed)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
        FROM client_usage 
       WHERE port = inPort AND name = inName
       )
       ;
```

Also does 'name' happen to be a reserved word in mysql ? Avoid it.

Comment: Syntax error.  MySQL does not support `INSERT ... VALUES ... WHERE`.  Additionally, the OP's problem is that a compound uniqueness constraint is needed on `(port, name)`.